# Cross Compiling for Raspi - Executing the programm ends in "Segmentation fault"

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I have a self-written programm which I want to build also for Raspberry Pi from my x86 machine. I'm using eclipse generated makefiles and cannot change this thing.

I've read this tutorial for CC for raspi : [Hackaday-Link](http://hackaday.com/2016/02/03/code-craft-cross-compiling-for-the-raspberry-pi/). Because raspi also have installed gcc version 4.9, I also try it with this version of the cross compiler. The problem also exisits with this hello world programm:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "hello world!" << endl;
}
```

When compiling and running it directly on the raspi, the output is `hello world!`. OK, thats fine.
But when cross-compiling it with version 4.9 of `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.9`, then scp it to the raspi, make it executable and run it, the output of `./hello_world` is `Segmentation fault`. When executing `sudo ./hello_world` there is no output.

I tried to get some information about the files and see that the locally on the raspi compiled program outputed:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ file hello_world
hello_world: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=41161ae762d940b12c3313ca065a3badd284f6d3, not stripped
```

and the cross-compiled version outputs

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ file hello_world
hello_world: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=4f1f4fb86710ef8130f148dc5adae1c0c18092fd, not stripped
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you put up the output from ldd hello_world

Comment: On your Pi, try gdb hello_world, then run the program and watch it segfault. Then use bt to get a backtrace, which should provide more information.

Comment: Output of the on raspi compiled one:
      `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ldd hello_world
      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0xb6f40000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6e52000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6dd7000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6daa000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6c69000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x7f57c000)`

Comment: and the cross compiled:
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ldd hello_world_cc 
        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0xb6f1f000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6e31000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6e04000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6cc3000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6c48000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x7f587000)`

Comment: @FrancescaNannizzi the output of gdb:
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gdb hello_world_cc 
...
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pi/hello_world_cc 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0005f7e2 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0005f7e2 in ?? ()
#1  0x0001062e in _start ()
(gdb)`

Comment: @alabamajack Unfortunately it looks like the stack trace is corrupted, so that's not much help. My best guess is that you cross-compiled with a different version of GLIBC than is running on the device.

Comment: Any news on that? I'm having this problem too.

Answer (score 2):

Toolchain compiler arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc can have different default parameters which one can get running:

```
 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Q --help=target
```

Compiler installed on Raspberry Stretch (I will leave essential information only):

`-march=                               armv6
  -marm                                 [enabled]
  -mfloat-abi=                          hard
  -mfp16-format=                        none
  -mfpu=                                vfp`

Stretch default cross-compiler:

`-march=                               armv7-a
  -marm                                 [disabled]
  -mfloat-abi=                          hard
  -mfp16-format=                        none
  -mfpu=                                vfpv3-d16`

Now you see the difference in architecture. So to sompile with cross-compiler one will need to set `march` to match your desired CPU. 
Also note that Debian cross compiler by default emits Thumb code and Raspberry Stretch emits ARM code

I suggest you're cross-compiling for newer CPU family while your device doesn't support it.