# Segmentation fault using pthread and arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads, cross-compiling

I have been trying all day to fix a **segmentation fault** that only occurs on one device. But from the beginning...

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pthread.h"

void* start_rtn(void* param);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Hallo World\n");

    pthread_t tid;
    int err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, start_rtn, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    printf("Exit\n");
}

void* start_rtn(void* param)
{
    printf("Thread test\n");
}
```

And here are the relevant parts of my CMakeList.txt:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
file(GLOB SOURCES "main.c")
add_executable(test ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(test -pthread)
```

This test application works on all my ARM devices except one. The one ARM device immediately delivers a segmentation fault. When I run gdb the following output appears:

```
warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 10825]

warning: File "/lib/libthread_db-1.0.so" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".

warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.

warning: File "/lib/libthread_db-1.0.so" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".

warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
Core was generated by `./test'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

But... If I compile the same application on my Raspberry Pi, it is working even on the special device.
If I remove the call to `pthread_create` it is working no matter on which device it was compiled.
So there seems to be a problem with my cross compiler, but this is only noticeable on the specific device and only if pthread methods are used.
I am helpless and grateful for every hint

This is ldd of the none working executable:

```
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6f2e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb6e02000)
    ld-linux-armhf.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6dda000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f4d000)

    Version information:
    ./testapp:
            libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/libpthread.so.0
            ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
    /lib/libpthread.so.0:
            ld-linux.so.3 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
            ld-linux.so.3 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
    /lib/libc.so.6:
            ld-linux.so.3 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
            ld-linux.so.3 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
```

And this is ldd output from the working executable (compiled by raspberry pi)

```
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6ee1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb6db5000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f00000)

    Version information:
    ./testapp_working:
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
            libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/libpthread.so.0
    /lib/libpthread.so.0:
            ld-linux.so.3 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
            ld-linux.so.3 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
    /lib/libc.so.6:
            ld-linux.so.3 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
            ld-linux.so.3 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
```

P.S.: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002372/cross-compiling-for-raspi-executing-the-programm-ends-in-segmentation-fault) seems to be very equal. I have already made sure that all gcc parameters of my environment and the Raspberry-Pi are identical.

Edit - Compiler command requested by Erlkoenig:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -marm -march=armv6 -mfpu=vfp -mtp=soft -pthread -g2 -gdwarf-2 -DDEBUG -D LINUX -D _GNU_SOURCE -D _DEBUG -std=gnu11 -o CMakeFiles/testapp.dir/main.c.o -c main.c
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -marm -march=armv6 -mfpu=vfp -mtp=soft -pthread -g2 -gdwarf-2 -DDEBUG CMakeFiles/testapp.dir/main.c.o -o ARM/Debug/testapp -pthread
```

Edit - Additional gdb output requested by Erlkoenig:

```
Core was generated by `./testapp'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) disas
No function contains program counter for selected frame.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
#1  0xb6ecb5b0 in __pthread_initialize_minimal () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0xb6ec9ba0 in ?? () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
#3  0xb6ec9ba0 in ?? () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) info reg
r0             0xb6f08504       3069216004
r1             0xb6ee41e0       3069067744
r2             0x800fff 8392703
r3             0x0      0
r4             0xb6f08504       3069216004
r5             0xb6ee2000       3069059072
r6             0xb6d99050       3067711568
r7             0xaf     175
r8             0x0      0
r9             0xb6ee4198       3069067672
r10            0xb6ecb2e0       3068965600
r11            0x0      0
r12            0xb6e979e0       3068754400
sp             0xbe9bec30       0xbe9bec30
lr             0xb6ecb5b0       -1226000976
pc             0x0      0x0
cpsr           0x60000010       1610612752
(gdb) info thread
  Id   Target Id         Frame
* 1    LWP 24127         0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Edit - exakt CPU info requested by Erlkoenig:

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 1594.16
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x3
CPU part        : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 0

Hardware        : Altera SOCFPGA
```

Edit - objdump output requested by Erlkoenig:

```
test:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .init:

000004f4 <_init>:
 4f4:   e92d4008        push    {r3, lr}
 4f8:   eb000035        bl      5d4 <call_weak_fn>
 4fc:   e8bd8008        pop     {r3, pc}

Disassembly of section .plt:

00000500 <.plt>:
 500:   e52de004        push    {lr}            ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
 504:   e59fe004        ldr     lr, [pc, #4]    ; 510 <.plt+0x10>
 508:   e08fe00e        add     lr, pc, lr
 50c:   e5bef008        ldr     pc, [lr, #8]!
 510:   00010a9c        .word   0x00010a9c

00000514 <__cxa_finalize@plt>:
 514:   e28fc600        add     ip, pc, #0, 12
 518:   e28cca10        add     ip, ip, #16, 20 ; 0x10000
 51c:   e5bcfa9c        ldr     pc, [ip, #2716]!        ; 0xa9c

00000520 <printf@plt>:
 520:   e28fc600        add     ip, pc, #0, 12
 524:   e28cca10        add     ip, ip, #16, 20 ; 0x10000
 528:   e5bcfa94        ldr     pc, [ip, #2708]!        ; 0xa94

0000052c <pthread_self@plt>:
 52c:   e28fc600        add     ip, pc, #0, 12
 530:   e28cca10        add     ip, ip, #16, 20 ; 0x10000
 534:   e5bcfa8c        ldr     pc, [ip, #2700]!        ; 0xa8c

00000538 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>:
 538:   e28fc600        add     ip, pc, #0, 12
 53c:   e28cca10        add     ip, ip, #16, 20 ; 0x10000
 540:   e5bcfa84        ldr     pc, [ip, #2692]!        ; 0xa84

00000544 <pthread_create@plt>:
 544:   e28fc600        add     ip, pc, #0, 12
 548:   e28cca10        add     ip, ip, #16, 20 ; 0x10000
 54c:   e5bcfa7c        ldr     pc, [ip, #2684]!        ; 0xa7c

00000550 <puts@plt>:
 550:   e28fc600        add     ip, pc, #0, 12
 554:   e28cca10        add     ip, ip, #16, 20 ; 0x10000
 558:   e5bcfa74        ldr     pc, [ip, #2676]!        ; 0xa74

0000055c <__libc_start_main@plt>:
 55c:   e28fc600        add     ip, pc, #0, 12
 560:   e28cca10        add     ip, ip, #16, 20 ; 0x10000
 564:   e5bcfa6c        ldr     pc, [ip, #2668]!        ; 0xa6c

00000568 <__gmon_start__@plt>:
 568:   e28fc600        add     ip, pc, #0, 12
 56c:   e28cca10        add     ip, ip, #16, 20 ; 0x10000
 570:   e5bcfa64        ldr     pc, [ip, #2660]!        ; 0xa64

00000574 <pthread_join@plt>:
 574:   e28fc600        add     ip, pc, #0, 12
 578:   e28cca10        add     ip, ip, #16, 20 ; 0x10000
 57c:   e5bcfa5c        ldr     pc, [ip, #2652]!        ; 0xa5c

00000580 <abort@plt>:
 580:   e28fc600        add     ip, pc, #0, 12
 584:   e28cca10        add     ip, ip, #16, 20 ; 0x10000
 588:   e5bcfa54        ldr     pc, [ip, #2644]!        ; 0xa54

Disassembly of section .text:

0000058c <_start>:
 58c:   f04f 0b00       mov.w   fp, #0
 590:   f04f 0e00       mov.w   lr, #0
 594:   bc02            pop     {r1}
 596:   466a            mov     r2, sp
 598:   b404            push    {r2}
 59a:   b401            push    {r0}
 59c:   f8df a024       ldr.w   sl, [pc, #36]   ; 5c4 <_start+0x38>
 5a0:   a308            add     r3, pc, #32     ; (adr r3, 5c4 <_start+0x38>)
 5a2:   449a            add     sl, r3
 5a4:   f8df c020       ldr.w   ip, [pc, #32]   ; 5c8 <_start+0x3c>
 5a8:   f85a c00c       ldr.w   ip, [sl, ip]
 5ac:   f84d cd04       str.w   ip, [sp, #-4]!
 5b0:   4b06            ldr     r3, [pc, #24]   ; (5cc <_start+0x40>)
 5b2:   f85a 3003       ldr.w   r3, [sl, r3]
 5b6:   4806            ldr     r0, [pc, #24]   ; (5d0 <_start+0x44>)
 5b8:   f85a 0000       ldr.w   r0, [sl, r0]
 5bc:   f7ff efce       blx     55c <__libc_start_main@plt>
 5c0:   f7ff efde       blx     580 <abort@plt>
 5c4:   000109e8        .word   0x000109e8
 5c8:   00000034        .word   0x00000034
 5cc:   00000048        .word   0x00000048
 5d0:   0000004c        .word   0x0000004c

000005d4 <call_weak_fn>:
 5d4:   e59f3014        ldr     r3, [pc, #20]   ; 5f0 <call_weak_fn+0x1c>
 5d8:   e59f2014        ldr     r2, [pc, #20]   ; 5f4 <call_weak_fn+0x20>
 5dc:   e08f3003        add     r3, pc, r3
 5e0:   e7932002        ldr     r2, [r3, r2]
 5e4:   e3520000        cmp     r2, #0
 5e8:   012fff1e        bxeq    lr
 5ec:   eaffffdd        b       568 <__gmon_start__@plt>
 5f0:   000109c8        .word   0x000109c8
 5f4:   00000044        .word   0x00000044

000005f8 <deregister_tm_clones>:
 5f8:   4806            ldr     r0, [pc, #24]   ; (614 <deregister_tm_clones+0x1c>)
 5fa:   4b07            ldr     r3, [pc, #28]   ; (618 <deregister_tm_clones+0x20>)
 5fc:   4478            add     r0, pc
 5fe:   4a07            ldr     r2, [pc, #28]   ; (61c <deregister_tm_clones+0x24>)
 600:   447b            add     r3, pc
 602:   4283            cmp     r3, r0
 604:   447a            add     r2, pc
 606:   d003            beq.n   610 <deregister_tm_clones+0x18>
 608:   4b05            ldr     r3, [pc, #20]   ; (620 <deregister_tm_clones+0x28>)
 60a:   58d3            ldr     r3, [r2, r3]
 60c:   b103            cbz     r3, 610 <deregister_tm_clones+0x18>
 60e:   4718            bx      r3
 610:   4770            bx      lr
 612:   bf00            nop
 614:   00010a08        .word   0x00010a08
 618:   00010a04        .word   0x00010a04
 61c:   000109a4        .word   0x000109a4
 620:   0000003c        .word   0x0000003c

00000624 <register_tm_clones>:
 624:   4808            ldr     r0, [pc, #32]   ; (648 <register_tm_clones+0x24>)
 626:   4909            ldr     r1, [pc, #36]   ; (64c <register_tm_clones+0x28>)
 628:   4478            add     r0, pc
 62a:   4a09            ldr     r2, [pc, #36]   ; (650 <register_tm_clones+0x2c>)
 62c:   4479            add     r1, pc
 62e:   1a09            subs    r1, r1, r0
 630:   447a            add     r2, pc
 632:   0fcb            lsrs    r3, r1, #31
 634:   eb03 01a1       add.w   r1, r3, r1, asr #2
 638:   1049            asrs    r1, r1, #1
 63a:   d003            beq.n   644 <register_tm_clones+0x20>
 63c:   4b05            ldr     r3, [pc, #20]   ; (654 <register_tm_clones+0x30>)
 63e:   58d3            ldr     r3, [r2, r3]
 640:   b103            cbz     r3, 644 <register_tm_clones+0x20>
 642:   4718            bx      r3
 644:   4770            bx      lr
 646:   bf00            nop
 648:   000109dc        .word   0x000109dc
 64c:   000109d8        .word   0x000109d8
 650:   00010978        .word   0x00010978
 654:   00000050        .word   0x00000050

00000658 <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
 658:   b508            push    {r3, lr}
 65a:   4b0a            ldr     r3, [pc, #40]   ; (684 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x2c>)
 65c:   4a0a            ldr     r2, [pc, #40]   ; (688 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x30>)
 65e:   447b            add     r3, pc
 660:   447a            add     r2, pc
 662:   781b            ldrb    r3, [r3, #0]
 664:   b96b            cbnz    r3, 682 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x2a>
 666:   4b09            ldr     r3, [pc, #36]   ; (68c <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x34>)
 668:   58d3            ldr     r3, [r2, r3]
 66a:   b123            cbz     r3, 676 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x1e>
 66c:   4b08            ldr     r3, [pc, #32]   ; (690 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x38>)
 66e:   447b            add     r3, pc
 670:   6818            ldr     r0, [r3, #0]
 672:   f7ff ef50       blx     514 <__cxa_finalize@plt>
 676:   f7ff ffbf       bl      5f8 <deregister_tm_clones>
 67a:   4b06            ldr     r3, [pc, #24]   ; (694 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x3c>)
 67c:   2201            movs    r2, #1
 67e:   447b            add     r3, pc
 680:   701a            strb    r2, [r3, #0]
 682:   bd08            pop     {r3, pc}
 684:   000109a6        .word   0x000109a6
 688:   00010948        .word   0x00010948
 68c:   00000038        .word   0x00000038
 690:   00010992        .word   0x00010992
 694:   00010986        .word   0x00010986

00000698 <frame_dummy>:
 698:   e7c4            b.n     624 <register_tm_clones>
 69a:   bf00            nop

0000069c <main>:
 69c:   e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
 6a0:   e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4
 6a4:   e24dd018        sub     sp, sp, #24
 6a8:   e50b0018        str     r0, [fp, #-24]  ; 0xffffffe8
 6ac:   e50b101c        str     r1, [fp, #-28]  ; 0xffffffe4
 6b0:   e59f20b0        ldr     r2, [pc, #176]  ; 768 <main+0xcc>
 6b4:   e08f2002        add     r2, pc, r2
 6b8:   e59f30ac        ldr     r3, [pc, #172]  ; 76c <main+0xd0>
 6bc:   e7923003        ldr     r3, [r2, r3]
 6c0:   e5933000        ldr     r3, [r3]
 6c4:   e50b3008        str     r3, [fp, #-8]
 6c8:   e3a03000        mov     r3, #0
 6cc:   e59f309c        ldr     r3, [pc, #156]  ; 770 <main+0xd4>
 6d0:   e08f3003        add     r3, pc, r3
 6d4:   e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
 6d8:   ebffff9c        bl      550 <puts@plt>
 6dc:   ebffff92        bl      52c <pthread_self@plt>
 6e0:   e50b0010        str     r0, [fp, #-16]
 6e4:   e51b1010        ldr     r1, [fp, #-16]
 6e8:   e59f3084        ldr     r3, [pc, #132]  ; 774 <main+0xd8>
 6ec:   e08f3003        add     r3, pc, r3
 6f0:   e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
 6f4:   ebffff89        bl      520 <printf@plt>
 6f8:   e24b0014        sub     r0, fp, #20
 6fc:   e3a03000        mov     r3, #0
 700:   e59f2070        ldr     r2, [pc, #112]  ; 778 <main+0xdc>
 704:   e08f2002        add     r2, pc, r2
 708:   e3a01000        mov     r1, #0
 70c:   ebffff8c        bl      544 <pthread_create@plt>
 710:   e50b000c        str     r0, [fp, #-12]
 714:   e51b3014        ldr     r3, [fp, #-20]  ; 0xffffffec
 718:   e3a01000        mov     r1, #0
 71c:   e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
 720:   ebffff93        bl      574 <pthread_join@plt>
 724:   e59f3050        ldr     r3, [pc, #80]   ; 77c <main+0xe0>
 728:   e08f3003        add     r3, pc, r3
 72c:   e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
 730:   ebffff86        bl      550 <puts@plt>
 734:   e3a03000        mov     r3, #0
 738:   e59f1040        ldr     r1, [pc, #64]   ; 780 <main+0xe4>
 73c:   e08f1001        add     r1, pc, r1
 740:   e59f2024        ldr     r2, [pc, #36]   ; 76c <main+0xd0>
 744:   e7912002        ldr     r2, [r1, r2]
 748:   e5921000        ldr     r1, [r2]
 74c:   e51b2008        ldr     r2, [fp, #-8]
 750:   e0321001        eors    r1, r2, r1
 754:   0a000000        beq     75c <main+0xc0>
 758:   ebffff76        bl      538 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 75c:   e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
 760:   e24bd004        sub     sp, fp, #4
 764:   e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}
 768:   000108f0        .word   0x000108f0
 76c:   00000040        .word   0x00000040
 770:   00000130        .word   0x00000130
 774:   0000011c        .word   0x0000011c
 778:   00000078        .word   0x00000078
 77c:   000000e8        .word   0x000000e8
 780:   00010868        .word   0x00010868

00000784 <start_rtn>:
 784:   e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
 788:   e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4
 78c:   e24dd008        sub     sp, sp, #8
 790:   e50b0008        str     r0, [fp, #-8]
 794:   e59f3018        ldr     r3, [pc, #24]   ; 7b4 <start_rtn+0x30>
 798:   e08f3003        add     r3, pc, r3
 79c:   e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
 7a0:   ebffff6a        bl      550 <puts@plt>
 7a4:   e1a00000        nop                     ; (mov r0, r0)
 7a8:   e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
 7ac:   e24bd004        sub     sp, fp, #4
 7b0:   e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}
 7b4:   00000080        .word   0x00000080

000007b8 <__libc_csu_init>:
 7b8:   e92d 43f8       stmdb   sp!, {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, lr}
 7bc:   4607            mov     r7, r0
 7be:   4e0c            ldr     r6, [pc, #48]   ; (7f0 <__libc_csu_init+0x38>)
 7c0:   4688            mov     r8, r1
 7c2:   4d0c            ldr     r5, [pc, #48]   ; (7f4 <__libc_csu_init+0x3c>)
 7c4:   4691            mov     r9, r2
 7c6:   447e            add     r6, pc
 7c8:   f7ff ee94       blx     4f4 <_init>
 7cc:   447d            add     r5, pc
 7ce:   1b76            subs    r6, r6, r5
 7d0:   10b6            asrs    r6, r6, #2
 7d2:   d00a            beq.n   7ea <__libc_csu_init+0x32>
 7d4:   3d04            subs    r5, #4
 7d6:   2400            movs    r4, #0
 7d8:   f855 3f04       ldr.w   r3, [r5, #4]!
 7dc:   3401            adds    r4, #1
 7de:   464a            mov     r2, r9
 7e0:   4641            mov     r1, r8
 7e2:   4638            mov     r0, r7
 7e4:   4798            blx     r3
 7e6:   42a6            cmp     r6, r4
 7e8:   d1f6            bne.n   7d8 <__libc_csu_init+0x20>
 7ea:   e8bd 83f8       ldmia.w sp!, {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, pc}
 7ee:   bf00            nop
 7f0:   000106d6        .word   0x000106d6
 7f4:   000106cc        .word   0x000106cc

000007f8 <__libc_csu_fini>:
 7f8:   4770            bx      lr
 7fa:   bf00            nop

Disassembly of section .fini:

000007fc <_fini>:
 7fc:   e92d4008        push    {r3, lr}
 800:   e8bd8008        pop     {r3, pc}
```

Edit - [Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnENjWG24dXSooQb63smHII3yhzh4g?e=NpmTnu) you can download both executables

Comment: Please show the exact compiler command line, give the exact processor type, and show the output of the GDB commands `disas`, `bt`, `info reg` after the crash, and also the output of `arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -d the_executable`.

Comment: Thanks @Erlkoenig, I have added all information to the original post.

Comment: Hmm, please also show the gdb command result of `info thread`. Can you upload both the working and the non working executable somewhere and post a link?

Comment: Thanks @Erlkoenig, I added the gdb info and a download link

Comment: I can't find anything wrong... The only real difference between both files is that the crashing one is compiled with PIC. Strangely, it is marked as a "shared object" instead of an executable. Still, both versions work on my Beagle Bone Black. You could try compiling & linking with `-fno-PIC -no-pie`. Perhaps there is something wrong with the C library on that one target, and it doesn't like PIC-executables.

Comment: Thank @Erlkoenig, but adding `-fno-PIC -no-pie` did not make any change.

Comment: If you replace the calls to `pthread_create()` and `pthread_join()` with a direct call to `start_rtn( NULL );`,  do you still get the segmentation fault?  If not, what happens if you keep the threading calls but put them in an `if` statement that won't get executed?  Because it looks like your executable is failing in the `libpthread.so` initialization code.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHenle, if I call `start_rtn( NULL)` without any pthread-method the application terminates successfully. Even if I put an `if` around it no error occurs. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: @Thomas If you look at the `ldd` output from the non-working executable, you'll see `ld-linux-armhf.so.3` twice.  That's weird and a bit suspicious.  What do you get if do an `ldd` on `libpthread.so`?  What about other calls in `libpthread()`?  Do they cause the same failure?  Do you have `strace` available?  If you do, run the process under `strace` and see what's different between the "good" and "bad" executables.  I'd also compare the shared object configurations, starting with [`ldconfig`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHenle, this is the output of `ldd /lib/libpthread.so.0`:
`libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb6dd2000)`
`/lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0xb6efe000)`
Any call into one of the pthread methods causing this segmentation fault

Comment: @Thomas Is it the same on all your systems?

Comment: Yes there is `strage`. I analyzed the output. In the non-functional version there are a number of additional open() with ld-linux-armhf.so.3 like `open("tls/v7l/neon/vfp/ld-linux-armhf.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`, `open("tls/v7l/neon/ld-linux-armhf.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Now that I have spent two days on this problem, a solution seems to have been found.

On a RaspberryPi (on which the application starts successfully) there was always SIGABRT (signal 6) with "stack smashing detected". But these were unexplainable. So I decided to disable them (temporarily) via `-fno-stack-protector`.

The result: The application also starts on the special device and there are no crashes yet.

Is it possible that there is a bug of the cross compiler "gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf" in combination with stack smashing? The problem is reproducible with gcc version 7.5.0 and version 9.3.0.

To be honest, the story makes me very doubtful about my build setup.

This is the new ldd output:

```
ldd ./testapp
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6f6f000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb6e43000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f8e000)
```

Many thanks to all supporters

Answer (score 0):

`start_rtn` is not returning anything - it should return something, even if it's NULL.

You may find that on different platforms you'll have different patterns of uninitialised memory and registers.  On most platforms you're probably lucky.

That's not to say there could be an issue with loading the pthread lib as well - are you able to load the program with `gdb` and at least step in to the first few lines?

Also - is there the option of installing compilers on the target and performing a direct compile with that?  I know someone who set up a build server on a RPI when he failed to get a cross-compiler to work ;)

Comment: Thank you @Den-Jason. You are absolutely right that a `return NULL` is missing here. I have added it. Unfortunately the segmentation fault still occurs.

Comment: OK - I have edited the post with some more ideas :)

Comment: No I'm not able to step into the first line. I immediately receive a segmentation fault.
If I build it on a Raspberry Pi every thing is working even on the sepcial device. I had hoped not to use a Raspberry as build server.

Comment: OK - so if you're able to generate a working image you could at least start to look at the build artifacts and try to fathom what's different between the direct-compilation and cross-compilation.

Comment: On request of Erlkoenig I have already uploaded both binaries. Neither he nor I can identify the cause.

Comment: Wait, you can't run the first line of `main()`? Can you start the program [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10483702/4730685) and run individual instructions (`stepi`) until it crashes and post the GDB session?

Comment: Thanks @Erlkoenig for not giving up yet. Since only gdb 7.5 is available I am looking for the entry point first `Entry point: 0x52c`. If I set the breakpoint there and `run` the following error message appears: `Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Error accessing memory address 0x52c: Input/output error. `
If I repeat it with the working executable, I am getting `Entry point: 0x10410` and the procedure works as expacted.

Comment: OK, if I compile it with `-no-pie` I get `Entry point: 0x104ac`. If I set break point to entry point and hit `run`, I get Segmentation fault with back trace equal to original post